# I have a randomly recurring problem in Search Builder. Why do the drop-down lists of options sometimes collapse horizonally?

Tags: joomla, search

Screen shot of the collapsed filter options.
[image: Screen shot of the collapsed filter options]
CiviCRM 5.66.0  Joomla! 3.10.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search Builder is a legacy part of CiviCRM which is no longer actively maintained.

It is recommended to use [SearchKit](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/searching/searchkit/what-is-searchkit/) which is included with your version of CiviCRM and can do everything Search Builder could do and much more.

Comment: Maybe time to put a warning on that screen like on the api3 screen? It's still needed to edit saved searches/smart groups, but could discourage making new search builder searches.

Comment: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28274